# creating a VB.Net class method that can validate form controls

Tags: vb.net, forms, validation

I would like to create a VB.Net class method that validates data entered by user on a form. I would like to be in a position to call this method from all my forms in my code. I would like to achieve this by creating a method that loop through all the Listbox and Textboxes on a form making sure that is not empty and if its empty give user another chance to enter valid data. This is working on every form as subprocedure, however I do have four forms and I would like to write the code once and call it from all my four forms.

MY QUESTION is then why do I get an error message "Controls is not declared or it may be inaccessible due to its protection level" when I code like below on my For Each loop:

```
Public Class formsValidationClass

    Public Function validate()

        'validation happens here for either a List Box or Text
        For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is ListBox Then
            End If
        Next 'form validation ends here
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Have you included System.Windows.Forms or passed a reference from the Form you are looking to validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class or its `validate` method needs a way to access the form that you want to validate. One way to do that would be to pass the form to be validated to the `validate` method.

```
Public Function validate(myForm as Form) As Boolean
    For Each ctrl As Control In myForm.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is ListBox Then
            'do something about the control
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Alternatively, you might want to store an associated form with each instance of the formsValidationClass

```
Public Class formsValidationClass
    Private myForm as Form

    Sub New(theForm as Form)
        myForm = the Form
    End Sub

Public Function validate() As Boolean
    For Each ctrl As Control In myForm.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is ListBox Then
            'do something about the control
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to pass context of form into your class. (At least in the example.)

Please see what I mean (fixed version):

```vb
Public Function validate(form As Form)

    For Each ctrl As Control In form.Controls
    ....
```

This was only example. You can introduce `form` in various other ways, for example through a property or constructor of your class.